# Is there an efficient way to create a random bit mask in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to have a random bit mask that has some specified percent of `0`s. The function I devised is:

```
def create_mask(shape, rate):
    """
    The idea is, you take a random permutations of numbers. You then mod then
    mod it by the [number of entries in the bitmask] / [percent of 0s you
    want]. The number of zeros will be exactly the rate of zeros need. You
    can clamp the values for a bitmask.
    """
    mask = torch.randperm(reduce(operator.mul, shape, 1)).float().cuda()
    # Mod it by the percent to get an even dist of 0s.
    mask = torch.fmod(mask, reduce(operator.mul, shape, 1) / rate)
    # Anything not zero should be put to 1
    mask = torch.clamp(mask, 0, 1)
    return mask.view(shape)
```

To illustrate:

```
>>> x = create_mask((10, 10), 10)
>>> x

    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
    1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1
    0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
    0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
    1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1
    0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
    1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     1
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
[torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 10x10 (GPU 0)]
```

The main issue I have with this method is it requires the `rate` to divide the `shape`. I want a function that accepts an arbitrary decimal and gives approximately `rate` percent of 0s in the bitmask. Furthermore, I am trying to find a relatively efficient way of doing so. Hence, I would rather not move a `numpy` array from the CPU to the GPU. Is there an effiecient way of doing so that allows for a decimal `rate`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For anyone running into this, this will create a bitmask with approximately 80% zero's directly on GPU. (PyTorch 0.3)

```
torch.cuda.FloatTensor(10, 10).uniform_() > 0.8
```

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to create a bit mask directly on GPU with Pytorch is:

```py
import torch

tensor = torch.rand((3, 5), device="cuda") < 0.9

# tensor([[ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
#         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True],
#         [ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
#         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#         [ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
#         [ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
#         [ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True],
#         [ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#         [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True]],
#        device='cuda:0')
```

Comment: should be `rand` not `randn` right?

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense, I corrected the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use NumPy and cudamat:

```
import numpy as np
import cudamat as cm

gpuMask = cm.CUDAMatrix(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(10,10), p=[1./2, 1./2]))
```

where the elements of the list are fraction representations of the probabilities of your 1s and 0s.

Comment: Hi, doesn't this require a transfer from CPU to GPU though? I am trying to avoid that if possible. I am going to need a lot of the bitmasks.

Comment: Added conversion to tensor

Comment: I believe this solution still requires that numpy runs on the CPU first, and this is then the data is transfered to the GPU? I am trying to find a solution where everything is on the GPU without need for a transfer.

Comment: Nope. Already answered two of your questions though. Read the CUDA docs.

Comment: Ok, I'll upvote for now, I'm going to look in the docs a little bit before accepting. Thanks.

Comment: Updated to something more straightforward. Cudamat can use NumPy on the GPU