# Pytorch: How to create a random int tensor where a certain percent are of a certain value? For example, 25% are 1s, and rest 0s

Tags: pytorch

In pytorch I can create a random zero and one tensor with around %50 distribution of each

```
import torch 
torch.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(2, 5))
```

I am wondering how I can make a tensor where only 25% of the values are 1s, and the rest are zeros?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an efficient way to create a random bit mask in Pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216615/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-create-a-random-bit-mask-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my answer here: [How to randomly set a fixed number of elements in each row of a tensor in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162672/how-to-randomly-set-a-fixed-number-of-elements-in-each-row-of-a-tensor-in-pytorc/64170973#64170973)

Say you want a matrix with dimensions `n X d` where **exactly** 25% of the values in each row are 1 and the rest 0, `desired_tensor` will have the result you want:

```
n = 2
d = 5
rand_mat = torch.rand(n, d)
k = round(0.25 * d) # For the general case change 0.25 to the percentage you need
k_th_quant = torch.topk(rand_mat, k, largest = False)[0][:,-1:]
bool_tensor = rand_mat <= k_th_quant
desired_tensor = torch.where(bool_tensor,torch.tensor(1),torch.tensor(0))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `rand` to generate a random tensor between `0,1` and compare that to `0.25`:

```
(torch.rand(size=(2,5)) < 0.25).int()
```

Output:

```
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

Comment: This won't guarantee that exactly 25% of the values are 1! And especially for smaller matrices